# Python: Binding a socket to /dev/rfcommX

Tags: python, sockets, rfcomm

I have a script that loads a Firmware on an embedded device over a serial port. The script takes the /dev/xxx adress of the serial port as an argument.
I have a special setup, where I do this over Bluetooth.
I managed to connect via bluetooth to the module in python. However I just can't find any example/information on how to register the local socket in a serial device like /dev/rfcomm0.

```
####### ORCA Bluetooth uploader Script #######
#As an input argument the script needs the BT Adress of the racer.
#if none is given, the script looks for nearby devices.

import bluetooth
import subprocess
import sys
import os

 #Check if we received a BT ADDR
if sys.argv[-1] != 'bt_comm.py':
  #Define the Pin for binding and the connection Port
  #Our Pin is 0000
  pin = "0000"
  #The Bootoader is listening on Port 1 for a connection
  port = 1
  rfcomm_port = 0
  #The BT Addr we get from the command line input
  #TAG:TODO:Check the input for sanity
  addr = sys.argv[-1]

  #Build the Firmware image
  subprocess.call("python ./px_mkfw.py --image ../../Firmware_orca/Images/px4fmu.bin  >    orca_fw",shell=True)

  #Create an RFCOMM Socket
  server_sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

  #Connect to the device
  server_sock.connect((addr, port))
  print "Connected to ",addr
```

Here I need some way to register server_sock at /dev/rfcomm0

```
  #Call the px_uploader script
  subprocess.call("python ./px_uploader.py --port /dev/rfcomm%d orca_fw" % rfcomm_port,shell=True)

  #Close the connection
  server_sock.close()

else:
  #Look for BT Devices and print them
  discovered_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names = True, flush_cache = True, duration = 20)
  if discovered_devices is not None:
    for addr in discovered_devices:
      print "Found bluetooth device: ", addr
  else:
    print "Could not find any bluetooth device nearby"
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi, yes I did... Unfortunately I am no longer working on this project and have no access to the code anymore. Sorry!

Comment: No problem, makes sense considering how long ago that was. Thanks anyway.